# I want to make a responsive banner, that changes depending of the resolution screen with php, js and html

Tags: javascript, php, html, responsive, slide

I confess that I have a poor knowledge in php and js, but I'm trying to innovate and make a descent website.
So I made 2 different slides, one for desktop and one for mobile, got a shortcode and i'm trying to put that in a html widget using a js screen width detection and mentioning it in the php code. Maybe its wrong in lots of levels but as I said I have no knowledge about that, so obviously didn't work and the code just gave me a blank widget. What am I doing wrong?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  createCookie("width", $(window).width());
});
</script>

<?php
if ($_COOKIE["height"] => 768px) {
    echo do_shortcode('[URIS id=2822]');
} 
    else {
        echo do_shortcode('[URIS id=2883]');
    }

?>
```

The error message is:

```
768px) { echo do_shortcode('[URIS id=2822]'); } else { echo do_shortcode('[URIS id=2883]'); } ?>
```

Comment: Why not just bootstrap it instead? That's the way to go nowadays.

Comment: This won't work since you cannot execute php-code from the HTML-Module (at least not by default). 
I would recommend you to just execute both shortcodes and hide the one that is not relevant to your screen-width via css (or js if you prefer, but it's probably not necessary). This might be simpler if your technical knowledge isn't up to par ;)

Comment: @ChristophKern I have no words enough to say thank you... I was complexing the code so much for a simple answer! Now it works, thank you <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend @ChristophKern helped me and I realize it was simpler than I though, I just used html and css instead js and php. The full code is:

```
<style>
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) 
{
  #slider-pro-3-2883 
   {
    display: none;
   }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) 
{
  #slider-pro-3-2822 
   {
    display: none !important;
   }
}
</style>

[URIS id=2822]
[URIS id=2883]
```

Thank you Chris and Funk Forty Niner for the time spend to help me <3